# Button not processing onClick method

Tags: asp.net, aspbutton

I have a button on an ascx control that calls a method on the onClick event:

```
<asp:Button id="bUpdateText" onClick="FUpdate" ValidationGroup="Update" CausesValidation="False" Text="Update" cssclass="button" runat="server" />
```

Normally I use this control on it's own page and the button works. This time round however, I am loading this control into a Div that is present on the home page of my site (that way I can show the contents with a little bit of JQuery). However, when I bring the control in this way, the onClick event doesn't fire and I am not sure what could cause that.

Sorry I don't have any code sample but the nature of the site makes it difficult to provide any that would make sense.

In short, what would stop this event firing now?

p.s I have tried adding validation groups to all other buttons and validation controls on the page and there is only ONE form present on the page.

EDIT: I have only just added the validation stuff in to see if that does anything. By default it has been like this and still didn't work:

```
<asp:Button id="bUpdateText" onClick="FUpdate" Text="Update" cssclass="button" runat="server" />
```

As mentioned as well, this works when I use this control on it's own page (loaded directly into Default.aspx) so I don't think the case of onClick matters.

EDIT2: I have just noticed that when I click this button, other validation controls on my page are being triggered even though they have their own DIFFERENT validation group?! Taking these controls out doesn't help though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what is causing the issue.

This control that I am now including is called on the Page_Finalize() and I am guessing that by this point the viewstate has forgotten it needs to do anything. Loading this control on the page load sorts it out.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

To start, if you set the 'causesValidation' property to false, you do not need a validation group. 
Additionally, I believe that ASP cares about case when dealing with the OnClick command.

i.e. it should be OnClick not onClick

Yeah, annoying and small, but that might be your problem

Comment: Please see OP regarding your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebug to see what happen in `Update` validationGroup. it looks like your page execute only client-side button click because of `Update` validationGroup.

Comment: Please see OP regarding your comments.

Comment: In design view see the event property of your button. Button Click property is set your "FUpdate" method?